Selenium / How to select a value form a select-box?
I try to select the option "Psychatrie" on a website using the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
srv=Service()
link = "https://asu.kvs-sachsen.de/arztsuche/pages/search.jsf"    
driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10) 

driver.get (link) 
waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="searchForm:specialismDetail:selectWindow"]'))).send_keys("Psychatrie")

But i only get this error:
(selenium) C:\DEV\Fiverr2024\ORDER\schlosswaechter>python temp1.py
Checking Browser driver...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr2024\ORDER\schlosswaechter\temp1.py", line 23, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="searchForm:specialismDetail:selectWindow"]'))).send_keys("Psychatrie")
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.202)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7E2331522+60802]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E22AAC22]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E2167B13]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21B09F7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21AEB1A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21DAB7A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21AA7C6]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21DAD90]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21FA224]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21DA923]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21A8FEC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E21A9C21]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7E26341BD+3217949]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7E2676157+3488183]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7E266F0DF+3459391]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7E23EB8E6+823622]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E22B5FBF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E22B0EE4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E22B1072]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7E22A18C4]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8F4D0257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF8F676AA48+40]

How can i select this value from the select-box on the page?

You have made a typo in the word "Psychatrie". It should have been "Psychiatrie".
In addition, I've modified the code so that you first click on the drop-down menu and then search for the exact string from the options. Finally, by executing javascript, you can click on the item as the click() method throws an error.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
srv = Service()
link = "https://asu.kvs-sachsen.de/arztsuche/pages/search.jsf"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=srv, options=options)
waitWD = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get(link)

# First click on the drop-down menu
waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="searchForm:specialismDetail:selectWindow"]'))).click()

# Then search for the exact string
element = waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Psychiatrie']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

